# How would get html in a string to render as html

Tags: javascript, html, escaping

So I have this string:

```
var textToBeRendered='<h1>I am a string of text</h1>';
```

If I have a div on the DOM, how would I be able to render the string to the div element as an actual header?

So the DOM would contain:

```
<div>
   <h1>I am a string of text</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add/remove HTML inside div using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17650776/add-remove-html-inside-div-using-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try This ^_^ :**

```js
var textToBeRendered='<h1>I am a string of text</h1>';
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = textToBeRendered
```

```html
<div id="demo">
   <h1>I am a string of text</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: This is what I wanted.  I just had a really bad brain fart; I should've thought of this.  I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

Use `document.createElement` to create childNode. `textContent` to put a text inside the newly created element. Then use `appendChild` to append with the parent

HTML

```
<div id="somId">
</div>
```

JS

```
var textToBeRendered= document.createElement('h1');
textToBeRendered.textContent = "I am a string of text";
document.getElementById('somId').appendChild(textToBeRendered);
```

[EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/w9oejsta/)

Answer (score 0):

If you consider using jQuery, you could use `jQuery.parseHTML()`

Answer (score 0):

```
var textToBeRendered='<h1>I am a string of text</h1>';
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = textToBeRendered;
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Answer (score 0):

I find `insertAdjacentHTML` to be the most flexible. The first param is where it should be inserted in relation to the element it's called on. The second param is the string. you could even use it like this. `div.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<h1>I am a string of text</h1>');`

```js
    (function(div) {
      var textToBeRendered = '<h1>I am a string of text</h1>';
      div.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', textToBeRendered);
    }(document.querySelector('div')));
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use JQUERY to do that, the following code will help you

```
<div id="myHeader">
</div>

<script>
     $("myHeader").html("<h1>I am a string of text</h1>")
</script>
```