# Add div javascript and then edit in place jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, edit-in-place

I've used the code from [Add/remove HTML inside div using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17650776/add-remove-html-inside-div-using-javascript) to make it suite my needs but unable to make any added `<div>` or `<span>` editable with any of the edit in place scripts that I found.

As you can see the last editable field is working fine but any new fields added with "+" is not working.

Any help will be appreciated.

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://wosephjeber.com/inputizer/dist/inputizer.js"></script>
   
<script>function counter(){return( $(".border").length );}</script>
<input type="button" value="+" onclick="addRow()">
<div id="content">
</div>
<span class="border">1</span>
<span class="border">2</span>
<span class="border">3</span>
<span class="border">4</span>


<script type="text/javascript">
function addRow() {
    var count =$(".border").length+1;
    var div = document.createElement('div');

    div.className = 'border';
    div.innerHTML = '<span class="icounter">'+ count +'</span> <span class="inputize-me">This is editable</span> <span id="Display" class="ir"></span>\
        <input type="button" value="-" onclick="removeRow(this)">';

     document.getElementById('content').appendChild(div);
}

function removeRow(input) {
    document.getElementById('content').removeChild( input.parentNode );
}

</script>
<br><br>
<span class="inputize-me">This is editable</span>
 <script>
      $('.inputize-me').inputizer(function(value) {
        console.log(value);
      });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add contenteditable="true" to the editable element

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://wosephjeber.com/inputizer/dist/inputizer.js"></script>
   
<script>function counter(){return( $(".border").length );}</script>
<input type="button" value="+" onclick="addRow()">
<div id="content">
</div>
<span class="border">1</span>
<span class="border">2</span>
<span class="border">3</span>
<span class="border">4</span>


<script type="text/javascript">
function addRow() {
    var count =$(".border").length+1;
    var div = document.createElement('div');

    div.className = 'border';
    div.innerHTML = '<span class="icounter">'+ count +'</span> <span class="inputize-me" contenteditable="true">This is editable</span> <span id="Display" class="ir"></span>\
        <input type="button" value="-" onclick="removeRow(this)">';

     document.getElementById('content').appendChild(div);
}

function removeRow(input) {
    document.getElementById('content').removeChild( input.parentNode );
}

</script>
<br><br>
<span class="inputize-me" contenteditable="true">This is editable</span>
 <script>
      $('.inputize-me').inputizer(function(value) {
        console.log(value);
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks :-) You've saved me jumping from one editable script to another.

Comment: yw! of course you have to manage modified text with javascript

Comment: Hmm, I've just found that there is no requirement for extra javasctripts as long as I use contenteditable="true" in the html tag.

Comment: true! javascript can be used to save the edited text