# How to change the button of a form when it is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have the following form and after the "Join" button is clicked, it should change to a delete button. I want to change the text to say delete and change what it does.

This is my code:

```
<form action="riderJoin.php" method="post">
    <input type ="hidden" name = id value="<?php echo $row['post_id']; ?>" >
    <input type =submit  class="edit_btn " name = "submit"  value = "Join">         
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('edit_btn');

<?php if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { ?>
    var i = <?php echo $_SESSION['postId'] ; ?> - 1 ;
    var y = x[i];
    x[i].textContent = "Delete";
    x[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    x[i].style.color = "white";
<?php }?>
</script>
```

I have get the button by class name into var `x` and grab an item inside the x using `x[i]`, but when I try to change the text content it doesn't change. However, when I set the background colour to red, it works perfectly.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the HTML that has the element itself so we can understand whats going wrong. It would also help if yo ucould add it as a working snippet, see
[How to create a runnable code snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: I have added some html code for better understanding. Thanks for your kind reminder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE: Change the Button Text**

When you create the button, you can see that the text you want to change is in the `value` attribute:

```
<input type =submit  class="edit_btn" name = "submit" value = "Join">
```

so this is what you want to change - not the `textContent` e.g.

```
  x[i].value = "Delete";
```

**UPDATE: Change the Form action**

To also change the action, first you'll need to add an id to your form so we can find in it the javascript, e.g.

```
<form action="riderJoin.php" method="post" id="subscriptionform">
```

And then in the javascript, you can get it and change the action like this:

```
var formelement = document.getElementById('subscriptionform');
formelement.action = "newAction.php"; // set the action to whatever page you want
```

**Working example**: click the button to change the text and the new action will also be displayed

```js
function changebutton() {

    // get the button and change it
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName('edit_btn');
    x[0].value = "Delete";
    x[0].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    x[0].style.color = "white";

    // change the action of the form
    var formelement = document.getElementById('subscriptionform');
    formelement.action = "yourNewAction.php";

    // Just for testing - gets the form action & displays it
    updateStatusText();
}

// Just for testing - gets the form action & displays it
function updateStatusText(){
    var formelement = document.getElementById('subscriptionform');
    currentaction = formelement .action;
    var textelement = document.getElementById('actiontext');
    textelement.innerText= "The form action is: "+currentaction;
}
updateStatusText();
```

```html
<form action="yourAction.php" method="post" id="subscriptionform">
    <input type=submit class="edit_btn " name="submit" value="Click Me..." onclick="changebutton();  return false;">
</form>

<p id="actiontext"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help ! So, what if I want to append a new element (another button) instead of just changing the value of that input? :D

Comment: @YeungHarry well that's a different question, so technically you should ask it as a new question, but let me know what you mean and I'll see if it fits within the scope of this one. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you want to change the action of the "Join" button to another function? Or do you want to remove the "Join button" and add a new one? Or add another button *and* keep the "Join" button?

Comment: I would like to remove the "join" button and try to add a "delete" button which can trigger another action

Comment: @YeungHarry Why not just keep the existing button and just change the action? I'll update my answer to do that because your question can be updated so its still applicable.

Comment: @YeungHarry I've updated my answer. Obviously I can't show you the change action fully because we can't submit the form, but I've added a test function the gets and displays the form action so that you can see that it changes.

Comment: What if I really want to prepend a new "delete" button (with a new action) right before the "join" button ? What should I do？

Comment: @YeungHarry Well, you can prepend another button, but a form can only have one action regardless of how many buttons it has, so you'd still need to change the action through Javascript in the same way. If you want to add an additional button, take a look at the code in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17650776/add-remove-html-inside-div-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with jquery in just one line...

```
$('input.edit_btn').eq(i).val('Delete').css({ 'background-color':'red', 'color':'white' });
```

I hope it helps

Comment: You shouldn't use .css() but .addClass() instead