# jQuery created fields not sending POST data to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

My code is not getting any post data from the jQuery created fields in my form. I commented out a lot of the code to see exactly what was happening, but my $_POST is only receiving the Fields that are set manually in html.

The jQuery created fields on the page show up and allow me to enter data. So I can't understand why I am not receiving any post data after a submit in my php code. Is there a way to capture the data in those fields and save them before a submit?

```
      <?php

    session_start();
    require_once "pdo.php";

    // Demand a GET parameter
    if ( ! isset($_SESSION['user_id']) || strlen($_SESSION['user_id']) < 1  ) {
        die('ACCESS DENIED');
    } else {
        $username = $_SESSION['who'];
        $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    }

    if ( isset($_POST['cancel'] ) ) {
        // Redirect the browser to game.php
        unset($_SESSION['first_name']);
        unset($_SESSION['last_name']);
        unset($_SESSION['email']);
        unset($_SESSION['headline']);
        unset($_SESSION['summary']);
        header("Location: index.php?name=".urlencode($_SESSION['who']));
        return;
    }

    if ( isset($_POST['clear']) ) {
        $first_name = '';
        $last_name = '';
        $email = '';
        $headline = '';
        $summary = '';
        unset($_POST);
    }

    if ( isset($_POST['headline']) && isset($_POST['summary']) && isset($_POST['email']) 
        && isset($_POST['first_name']) && isset($_POST['last_name'])) {
        //$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        //$headline = $_POST['headline'];
        $findme = "@";
        $pos = strpos($email, $findme);

        if ( strlen($_POST['headline']) < 1 || strlen($_POST['last_name']) < 1 
                || strlen($_POST['first_name']) < 1 || strlen($_POST['email']) < 1
                || strlen($_POST['summary']) < 1){
            $_SESSION['error'] = "All Fields Are Required";
            header("Location: add.php?name=".urlencode($_SESSION['who']));
            return;
        } 
        elseif ( $pos === FALSE ) {
                $_SESSION['error'] = "Email must have an at-sign (@)";
                header("Location: add.php");
                return;
        }
        else {
            foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
                echo "POST Field ".htmlspecialchars($key)." is ".htmlspecialchars($value)."<br>";
            }

            foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
                echo "GET Field ".htmlspecialchars($key)." is ".htmlspecialchars($value)."<br>";
            }

            $_SESSION['first_name'] = $_POST['first_name'];
            $_SESSION['last_name'] = $_POST['last_name'];
            $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
            $_SESSION['headline'] = $_POST['headline'];
            $_SESSION['summary'] = $_POST['summary'];
           // header("Location: add.php");
            //return;
        }
    }

    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
</p>    
<form id="form" method="post">
<p>First Name:
<input type="text" name="first_name" size="60" value="<?= htmlentities($first_name) ?>"/></p>
<p>Last Name:
<input type="text" name="last_name" size="60" value="<?= htmlentities($last_name) ?>"/></p>
<p>Email:
<input type="text" name="email" value="<?= htmlentities($email) ?>"/></p>
<p>Headline:
<input type="text" name="headline" value="<?= htmlentities($headline) ?>"/></p>
<p>Summary:<br/>
<textarea name="summary" rows="8" cols="80" value="<?= htmlentities($summary) ?>"></textarea></p>
<p>Position: <input type="submit" name="addPos" id="addPos" value="+">
<div id="position_fields">
</div>
<input type="submit" id="add" value="Add">
<input type="submit" name="clear" value="Clear">
<input type="submit" name="cancel" value="Cancel">

</form>
<script>
countPos = 0;

// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17650776/add-remove-html-inside-div-using-javascript
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.console && console.log('Document ready called');
    $('#addPos').click(function(event){
        // http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("Does this work?");
        if ( countPos >= 9 ) {
            alert("Maximum of nine position entries exceeded");
            return;
        }
        countPos++;
        window.console && console.log("Adding position "+countPos);
        $('#position_fields').append(
            '<div id="position'+countPos+'"> \
            <p>Year: <input type="text" name="year'+countPos+'" value="" /> \
            <input type="button" value="-" \
                onclick="$(\'#position'+countPos+'\').remove();return false;"></p> \
            <textarea name="desc'+countPos+'" rows="8" cols="80"></textarea>\
            </div>');
    });


    $('#add').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = $('#form');
    var year = form.find('input[name="year'+countPos+'"]').val();
    var desc = form.find('textarea[name="desc'+countPos+'"]').val();
    var test = $('#form').serialize();
    alert ('You a beast');
    alert(countPos);
    alert(test['summary']);
    //alert(desc);
    alert($('#form').serialize());
    //alert(form.find('textarea[name="desc1"]')).val();
    // Executes an AJAX's POST request
    $.post(

      // replace with the URL that will process the POST request
      'postdata.php',

      // here is where the magic happens
      // form.serialize get data from all fields
      // in your form object and submit them via AJAX
      { 'val': year,'val2': desc,'val3': countPos},

      // Here you process the server's response
      function(data) {
        // do something with your data
        window.console && console.log("Postdata "+data);
        //console.log(data);
       // console.log(postdata);
        //alert(console.log(data));
        //alert(console.log(postdata));
      }
    ).error( function() { 
      $('#form').css('background-color', 'red');
      window.console && console.log("No Post data "+data);
      alert("Didn't work! "+data);
    });
    });
});

</script>
</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that since you're adding fields on the fly, the DOM doesn't know that they exist.

All you have to do is to call `form.serialize()` so that you can get all data from your form fields.

I've created a small working example so that you can see what you should do:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var form = $('form');
  var fields = $('#fields');
  
  var add_button = $('#add');
  add_button.click(function(event) {
    console.log('Add a new field');
    
    // Notice I'm using backtick instead of quotes
    // It's easier to read and add data dinamically
    fields.append(`
      <div>
        <label for="field_${count}">Field #${count}</label><br />
        <input type="text" name="field_${count}" id="field_${count}" />
      </div>
    `);
    
    count++;
  });
  
  var count = 1;
  var submit_button = $('#submit');
  submit_button.click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    
    // Executes an AJAX's POST request
    $.post(
    
      // replace with the URL that will process the POST request
      'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
      
      // here is where the magic happens
      // form.serialize get data from all fields
      // in your form object and submit them via AJAX
      form.serialize(),
      
      // Here you process the server's response
      function(data) {
        // do something with your data
        console.log(data);
      }
    );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form" method="post">
  <div>
    <input type="button" id="add" value="Add" />
  </div>
  <div id="fields">
    <div>
      <label for="first_name">First Name</label><br />
      <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="first_name">Last Name</label><br />
      <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
  </div>
</form>
```