# what would be the call syntax for these javascript functions?

Tags: javascript, html

so i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17650776/add-remove-html-inside-div-using-javascript/17650902#17650902?newreg=8966f89f16e3406c82fec06e4992a031) thread, but I can't figure out how to actually call the functions.

i have tried:

```
removeRow('message')
```

and

```
removeRow(document.getElementById('message'))
```

i am using the accepted answer and my html is

```
      <form action="http://localhost/signup.php" method="post" style="display:inline-block; margin:0 auto;">
         <label for="username">Username</label>
         <br>
         <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" required>
         <br>
         <label for="password">Password</label>
         <br>
         <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" onkeyup='check();' required>
         <br id="message">
         <p id="message"></p>
         <br id="message">
         <label for="confirm_password">Confirm Password</label>
         <br>
         <input type="password" name="confirm_password" id="confirm_password" placeholder="Password" onkeyup='check();' required>
         <br>
         <label for="Email">Email Address</label>
         <br>
         <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required>

         <button type="submit" id="signup">
            Sign up
         </button>
      </form>
```

Comment: When do you want the function to work exactly? When clicking the signup button?

Comment: it should work alongside the check function that is executed by both passwords with onkeyup

Comment: So you want to remove the `p` tag by executing the `removeRow` function?

Comment: edited the code. i want all elements with the id of message to get removed and added

Comment: Add the function declaration `function removeRow(elementId){ document.getElementById(elementId) }` and call it with `onkeyup="removeRow('message')" `. Is it what you need?

Comment: If you copy/pasted from that other post, the removeRow function they defined there is specifically looking for an element that is a child of 'content.' I'm guessing that might be what happened, but you didn't include your function definitions.

Answer (score 0):

The function in the original answer is :

```
function removeRow(input) {
    input.parentNode.remove()
}
```

So the expected parameter of the function is an element and the function removes element's parent.
If you want to remove the element with id #message, just change the function to:

```
function removeRow(element) {
  element.remove()
}
```

PS: the ids  should be unique, if you have multiple element with the same you should use a class
and the selector will be `document.getElementsByClassName("message")`